# where I can find Ext.ux.CheckColumn

Tags: extjs4

I switched from Exjts 3 .1.1 to 4 and they have an example using Ext.ux.CheckColumn, can anyone tell me where I cand find the file, because I can only find the old version Ext.ux.grid.CheckColumn.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's in the examples folder

`ext-4.0.2a/examples/ux/CheckColumn.js`